# Cannot seem to swap rows in an array of records in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Cannot seem to be able to swap two rows in a table. As you can see position one successfully copies to position 0 but not the other way around? The data for each position is stored before the swap so It's not as if the computer is taking the new overwritten data and is putting it into the new position.

CODE:

````
```
import numpy as np

name = ['Alice1', 'Bob', 'Cathy', 'Doug']
age = [25, 45, 100, 19]
weight = [55.0, 85.5, 68.0, 61.5]

data = np.zeros(4, dtype={'names': ('name', 'age', 'weight'), 'formats': ('U10', 'i4', 'f8')})

data['name'] = name
data['age'] = age
data['weight'] = weight

pos0 = data[0]
pos1 = data[1]

data[0] = pos1
data[1] = pos0

print(data)
```
````

OUTPUT:

````
```
ORIGIONAL LIST: [('Alice1',  25, 55. ) ('Bob',  45, 85.5) ('Cathy', 100, 68. )
('Doug',  19, 61.5)]
NEW SWAPPED LIST: [('Bob',  45, 85.5) ('Bob',  45, 85.5) ('Cathy', 100, 68. )
('Doug',  19, 61.5)]
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How's this for readability?

```
data[[0,1]] = data[[1,0]]
```

This in a way does the same as the idiom for immutable objects `a,b = b,a` in that it sacrifices speed (a few unnecessary copies are made) for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [numpy.copy](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html):

```
data[0], data[1] = data[1], data[0].copy()
```

Comment: One copy (the second one) is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the tuple object in your code and not the content of it. Therefore, when you swap the first element `data[0] = pos1`, `pos0`'s content also changes (it is pointing to the object and not the content). If you want to swap content use copy:

```
from copy import deepcopy
pos0 = deepcopy(data[0])
pos1 = deepcopy(data[1])
data[0] = pos1
data[1] = pos0
```

output:

```
print(data)

[('Bob',  45, 85.5) ('Alice1',  25, 55. ) ('Cathy', 100, 68. )
 ('Doug',  19, 61.5)]
```

Comment: `data[0]` is an array element, type `numpy.void`, though it does display as a tuple.  `data[0].copy()` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The first pair of assignments create a reference to the data rows. The second pair of assignments change the contents of the data rows. Hence, the reference `pos0` now refers to `data[0]` *with the updated content* when it is assigned to `data[1]`.

The usual way to swap things in Python goes like

```py
 data[0], data[1] = data[1], data[0]
```

but this does not work with `numpy` arrays either, so

```py
data[:2] = data[1::-1]
```

seems to be the right solution here. The index slice `1::-1` means `first_index:last_index:increment`, where the last index remained unspecified.

Comment: I disagree with the claim that "both ways look like perfectly acceptable code." The second one is much less readable.

Comment: I updated the answer, as I realized that _only_ the second does what it is supposed to do on `numpy` arrays. I am not sure there is a more readable version of it.

Comment: Technically these aren't array rows.  It's a 1d array, with a compound dtype.  Still the issue is similar.  `data[0]` is a view of `data`.